# Basic probability

Tags: probability, independence

Can we prove $P(A\cap B) = P(A)P(B)$, if $A$ and $B$ are independent events?

Comment: By definition, $A$ and $B$ are independent events iff $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$.

Comment: That is the definition, isn't???

Comment: Was thinking if it can be proved using probability axioms.

Comment: What does probability axiom would do here! Those axioms do not include independence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want this:

You know $P(A\mid B)=\dfrac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$

Since independent $P(A\mid B)=P(A)$

Hence, $$P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)\space\space\space\space\space\blacksquare$$

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to understand this, rather than just have a formula, you should think about this conceptually:

Conceptually, events $A$ and $B$ are independent if the probability of event $A$ is unaffected by the happening (or not happening) of event $B$.

For example, whether it rains outside does not affect whether a coin lands on heads or not, so these are independent events.

Moreover, given that the probability of the coin landing on heads is $\frac{1}{2}$, it will *remain* $\frac{1}{2}$ when it is raining or not; knowing that it rains does not help me figure out as to whether the coin lands on heads or not.

In other words, if $A$ and $B$ are independent, then we have $P(A) =P(A|B)$

But since we *always* have that $P(A \cap B)=P(A|B)\cdot P(B)$, we thus get:

$P(A\cap B) = P(A)\cdot P(B)$